# append a table from onMouseHover value to other div

Tags: jquery, onmouseover

i have this span:

```
<span onmouseover="Tip( '<table>blablabla</table>' ,WIDTH, -350 ,TITLE,'Tip!' );" onmouseout="UnTip()" >
<img src="http://yooploo.com/images/M_images/con_info.png" alt="" align="top" border="0" />&nbsp;
</span>
```

i want to take the

```
<table>blablabla</table>
```

and append it to a div (of course, the table's content is not really blablabla)
how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

After adding a  to your html, the following works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 var val = $("span").attr("onmouseover");
 var re = new RegExp("<table>(.*)</table>", "i");
 var r = val.match(re);   
 $("#result").html(r[0]);

});
```

Here the [jsFiddle working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/mLCwQ/)